# Spring Boot Embedded Kafka can't connect

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to write an integration test for my Kafka consumer. I've followed through with the [official reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/#reference) but when I start my test I only see this repeated ad infinitum:

> -2019-04-03 15:47:34.002 WARN 13120 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer
>   clientId=consumer-1, groupId=my-group] Connection to node -1 could not
>   be established. Broker may not be available.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using JUnit5, Spring Boot and `spring-kafka` and `spring-kafka-test`.

I have the `@EnableKafka` annotation on my `@Configuration` class.

This is how my test class looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [TestKafkaConfig::class])
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 1,
        topics = [KafkaIntegrationTest.MY_TOPIC])
class KafkaIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var embeddedKafka: EmbeddedKafkaBroker

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(embeddedKafka.brokersAsString)
        val template = KafkaTemplate(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Int, String>(senderProps))
        template.defaultTopic = KafkaIntegrationTest.MY_TOPIC
        template.sendDefault("foo")
    }
}
```

my `application.yml` looks like this:

```
kafka:
  consumer:
    group-id: my-group
    bootstrap-servers: ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}
    value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: ${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:http://localhost:8081}
      specific.avro.reader: true
```

I also tried setting up a `MockSchemaRegistryClient` but I get the exact same repeated message. (This is how I tried to set up the `MockSchemaRegistryClient`):

```
@TestConfiguration
@Import(TestConfig::class)
class TestKafkaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var props: KafkaProperties

    @Bean
    fun schemaRegistryClient() = MockSchemaRegistryClient()

    @Bean
    fun kafkaAvroSerializer() = KafkaAvroSerializer(schemaRegistryClient())

    @Bean
    fun kafkaAvroDeserializer() = KafkaAvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient(), props.buildConsumerProperties())

    @Bean
    fun producerFactory(): ProducerFactory<*, *> = DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(
            props.buildProducerProperties(),
            StringSerializer(),
            kafkaAvroSerializer())

    @Bean
    fun consumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<*, *> = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(
            props.buildConsumerProperties(),
            StringDeserializer(),
            kafkaAvroDeserializer()
    )

    @Bean
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory() = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Any, Any>().apply {
        setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory() as ConsumerFactory<in Any, in Any>?)
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
**Note that** I'm using the Confluent Schema Registry and try to deserialize from Avro.

What I'm trying to test is whether my consumer works or not which looks like this:

```
open class SomeConsumer(private val someUseCase) {

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["\${kafka.some-topic}"])
    open fun processMessage(record: ConsumerRecord<String, SomeObject>) {
        someUseCase.call(record)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you're missing setting the broker url for your tests.

There is a note about how to get this value in the documentation:

> When the embedded Kafka and embedded Zookeeper server are started by the EmbeddedKafkaBroker, a system property named spring.embedded.kafka.brokers is set to the address of the Kafka brokers and a system property named spring.embedded.zookeeper.connect is set to the address of Zookeeper. Convenient constants (EmbeddedKafkaBroker.SPRING_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_BROKERS and EmbeddedKafkaBroker.SPRING_EMBEDDED_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT) are provided for this property.

(It's located at the bottom of the junit section [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/#junit))

One way to fix this is to set `kafka.consumers.bootstrap-servers` to this value in your tests, e.g.

```
spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
            bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

Comment: My `@KafkaListener` still doesn't work though. It gets created, but I doesn't receive the message I send with the `KafkaTemplate`. My error handler isn't called either.

Comment: Do you no longer get the `Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.` message? if so then you are at least sucessfully connecting to the embedded broker.

Comment: Yes. I mean I don't get it anymore. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One other thing I've noticed is you're creating the topic `KafkaIntegrationTest.MY_TOPIC` on the embedded broker, but sending the message to `template.defaultTopic = INSERTED_VARIANT_TOPIC`, is it possible you have a topic mismatch?

Comment: No, I just forgot to replace it with `MY_TOPIC` in the example. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it working. I had to set up my producer in the same way as the consumer since I'm producing Kafka records in the test and now everything is working including the mock schema registry. Note that the mock schema registry needs the Avro file registered as well.

Comment: This resolved my issue after upgrading to spring-kafka 3.1.2